# windows phone 8 save pictures in server

Tags: image, upload, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to share a picture and some strings between few devices.
The strings are saved in an SQL Database, but as I understood it's not recommended to upload pictures to the Database.
Where should I store the pictures?

thank you!

Comment: If you don't want to store the pictures in the database, you can store them directly to the isolated storage, then store only the path to the file in the database

Comment: I want the pictures to be accessible by few different devices

Comment: Do you mean, where do you store the pictures _on the server_? If so, this question has nothing to do with wp8. Otherwise, I don't understand what you mean by "accessible by few different devices".

Comment: best way is to use an API with an upload method that will store the pictures directly into the server's directory (or to a shared directory if there are multiple servers) and then keep the link into your SQL database under that object. then all the requests for that object would know the path for your picture and download it.